# get all user profile user in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

how to programatically get all the profile user?

please suggest the any code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get UserProfile information you can use the UserProfileManager.

To get them all:

```
UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(yourservercontext);

foreach (UserProfile profile in upm)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: FYI: Needs a reference to Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles

Comment: Can i use the above code on a remote machine, or it is mandatory to run the code on share point server ??